# ListView.SelectionChanged to RoutedCommand

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm, routed-commands

I'm working in the MVVM design pattern with WPF.  I have a `ContextMenu` with several items in it on a `ListView`.  Based on the number of items selected in the `ListView`, I want to enable/disable certain `MenuItem`s.  Is there a way to route the `SelectionChanged` event along with the number of selected items in the `ListView` directly to the view model.  If so, I can define a dependency property in the VM for `IsEnabled` quite easily.  I'm just trying to avoid code-behind to handle this.

Kelly

Comment: Do you mean just:
listView1.SelectionChanged += .. ? i guess not.. but i didn't understand..

Comment: I'm aware of how to hook up the event with code behind.  What I'm trying to do is handle the event via a RoutedCommand in the ViewModel without any code behind.  Thanks, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an attached behavior to route the SelectionChanged event to your VM. Basically, you create an attached property of type bool. When this property is set to true, you register an event handler for the SelectionChanged event of the target Menu.

Then an attached property can contains the command to execute (databound to a RelayCommand-like command in your VM).

Check those posts for more details:

- http://www.japf.fr/2008/12/how-to-attach-commands-to-any-uielement/
- http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/